# to retrieve the list of stock data by product ID using catalogInventoryStockItemList in android using k2 soap

Tags: ecommerce-tracking

Hi I want to display is the stock of particular product available in my android app where I want to retrive the products through k2 soap api through 
catalogInventoryStockItemList  method plz can anyone guide me how to proceed to this?

```
     public  void getproductstock(){

    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, "catalogInventoryStockItemList");

    //SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope =new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);



    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.dotNet = true;

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);


    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try
    {

        androidHttpTransport.call("", envelope);

        SoapObject response = (SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();

           String result = response.getProperty(4).toString();

        tv_products.setText(result);




    }

    catch(Exception e)

    {


        e.printStackTrace();


    }


}
```

Sir but i am unable to fetch and display is_in_stock attribute of particular product in textview